# Programmatically Including Tables Within TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to add a table within a TreeView. Is this possible?
Here is the following C# code I am using to generate the TreeView:

```
        var items = tree1.Items;

        var item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "End Item 1" };
        items.Add(item);

        var assemblies = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Assemblies" };
        var endpart = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Parts" };

        foreach (TreeViewItem n in items)
        {

            /// ASSEMBLIES
            (n as TreeViewItem).Items.Add(assemblies);
            /// ASSEMBLIES - ASSEMBLY 1
            var subass = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Assembly 1" };
            foreach (TreeViewItem o in (n as TreeViewItem).Items)
            {
                if (o.Header == "Assemblies")
                {
                    (o as TreeViewItem).Items.Add(subass);
                    // TABLE of PARTS


                }

            }

            ///PARTS
            (n as TreeViewItem).Items.Add(endpart);

            ///PARTS - PART1
            var subendpart = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Part1" };
            foreach (TreeViewItem p in (n as TreeViewItem).Items)
            {
                if (p.Header == "Parts")
                    (p as TreeViewItem).Items.Add(subendpart);
            }


        }

    }
```

I want to retrieve data about each part and include it in a table under the Part heading. How can I go about this?

Comment: `if (o.Header == "Assemblies")` <-- WRONG. Do not base your application logic off of the state (property values) of UI elements. Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore besides being so critic about his code could you provide him with some sample code with what would be a good practice ?

Comment: @mauricioGracia [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode). I'm too lazy and I have a serious headache right now, I'm not in a condition to post an answer.

Comment: @HighCore as far as i can tell...that was an answer, hope you get better ;-)

Comment: @HighCore, thanks for the response and I will look into it. Regarding my question, this is what I am trying to achieve: http://imgur.com/LnKYylJ . However, I want to dynamically create this table and load content to it using C# and have it associated with a TreeViewItem.